# Javascript regexp - remove space between quotation marks

Tags: javascript, regex

i need to remove spaces just between quotation marks and just after style properties with regexp.

before:

```
<h2><span style="font-family: Georgia; font-size: 10pt;">Text</span></h2>
```

after:

```
<h2><span style="font-family:Georgia; font-size:10pt;">Text</span></h2>
```

It's important for me because i need to convert html code to rtf file.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression to capture the group containing the space looks like this:

```
".+?:(\s{1}).+?;"?
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but result is `style=>`, there is nothing, i use this `html.replace(/".+?:(\s{1}).+?;"?/g,"")`, did I something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want remove inside the style attribute you can use the following code

```
m = data.replace(/style="(.+?)"/,($1)=>{ 
 return $1.replace(/(?<=:)\s(?=\w)/g,'')
});
```

If you want replace anywhere in the string use following one

```
m = data.replace(/(?:(?<=:)\s(?=\w)|(?<=;)\s)/g,'')
```

Comment: @LukášMáška I handled to remove the space after ;

Answer (score 1):

This may help you :

```
(:\s)(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*"[^"]*$)
```

It will capture all ": " (colon followed by a whitespace) that are between two " (doublequotes). Then you could replace them by a single colon, that should do what you wish.

Comment: I still need to remove space after -> ; <-  to result: `style="font-size:15px;font-family:Arial;"` , thank you for answer, i cant solve it myself

Comment: If you need to remove all whitespace you could just use (\s) at the beginning of the regex and replace these whitespace found by nothing. Else, if it is just after : and ; you could use ((:|;)\s)